# Manga about a guy transporting in and out of a video game world, where he takes on quests for money

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

So this was a few years ago and it didn't have many chapters (maybe like 1-3 at most), but it's about a guy mc, and hes constantly transporting in and out of a videogame world, and (I'm guessing the rest of the world) makes money in the real world by taking on quests in the game, and he has no choice (or he gets sucked into this portal forcing him into the game world).

A scene I remember is he met a girl, and the girl died from this monster in the game, and when he returned to the real world she was also dead there as reported on the news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably *[Zero no Shiniki](https://myanimelist.net/manga/76191/Zero_no_Shiniki)*.

[image]

It only has three chapters, like you said, and the main character makes money by taking on quests in the game world. He also meets a girl in the first chapter who is killed and eaten by a large monster in the game world, and he later overhears a news report about her being found dead in her home in the real world.

Synopsis from MyAnimeList:

> Kanzaki Rei is an avid gamer, but one day he hit rock-bottom due to his debts. During the night while sleeping, a strange phenomenon happened and sent him inside the game he previously played. A world of life and death awaits.